# How to add customer email to order grid in magento 1.6

Tags: magento

i am using magento 1.6
and want to add cutomer email,coupon code and shipping detials to sales order grid

can you guys please tell me how to do that

it tried using this

```
copy
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
to
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

then under the following line

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

add

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfo'=>'sales_flat_order'),'sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sfo.customer_email'));

then in the _prepareColumns() method add

    $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Email'),
        'index' => 'customer_email',
        'filter_index' => 'sfo.customer_email',
    ));
note. you will need to add a 'filter_index' to all calls to addColumn pointing to main_table.field_name
```

but its not working

Comment: Are you working from a tutorial? Would you please give the link for it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have [found an extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/order-grid-manager-8044.html) to do exactly what you are seeking. There is also [this free extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-product-grid.html) but I do not know if it's strong enough to do what you need. Worst case, it is a starting point for you?? And I'm fairly sure [this extension does everything you want](http://www.mageworx.com/extended-orders-magento-extension.html)... I'm tempted to buy it!

As I often say, [better to buy an extension, so you won't write code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580712/magento-1-6-adding-custom-fields-for-registration-page/10606489#10606489).