# How do I add custom shipping and payment options to checkout in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.5

Running Magento 1.5.1.  My webstore contains a lot of products that get shipped direct from the manufacturer.  The cost of shipping is extremely variable, and due to the number of products we carry, it is unfeasible to determine shipping costs for many items.

I would like to add a "request quote" option during checkout.  The basic idea I have is this:

-Items without a weight or dimensions will be required to go through an RFQ (request for quote) process.  During checkout, if the user has an item in their cart that requires an RFQ (because it doesn't have weight or dimensions defined), it will present a single option for shipping: "Request quote for shipping".
-The next step is the payment screen.  Instead of actual payment options, a "pay invoice later" or "pay when quote is received" option will be present.  The user will be forced to select this (or perhaps we could skip the payment screen altogether?).

This seems like it should be relatively easy to hack together, but I'm wondering if I'm going about this the wrong way?  Is there an easier way to do this?  My thought is to modify the checkout code to check for weight or dimensions, if not, only show that one shipping option (I'd probably re-purpose "free shipping" to be that option).  Then, in the payment screen, check if free shipping is selected in the order, and then present the custom payment option (probably re-purpose cheque or money order option).  From there we'd send them an official quote via Paypal or something similar.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!!

Comment: sorry for bitching: yeah it is relatively easy :) go ahead and program a shipping method extension that takes account all your conditions. And after you are done then reprogram your payment methods to acknowledge the condition as well. Sad that the Magento development learning curve is 6 months or so. But relatively easy is relative anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll offer [my normal advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580712/magento-1-6-adding-custom-fields-for-registration-page/10606489#10606489): There are a ton of extensions to let this happen. My philosophy is to start looking at extensions before trying to code anything in magento. Is especially helpful when an upgrade breaks something; they'll usually fix upgrade problems that clearly affect their own extensions for free.

In your case there is a free custom shipping option extension I use for "Will Call" which you can use for "RFQ" purposes. I strongly advise against messing with payment modules. I have written 6 or more "payment" things in PHP for live sites and admin back-end use. Until you really understand Magento, you are wasting your time and money writing code. If your question is to get a website working so you can make money, go buy extensions that get the job done...

To go on about writing code, I hand rolled some code in the contact form to add google re-capcha as well as to have customers select from existing product attributes (vehicle year, make, model). I was eventually able to figure out how to have these reflect in the emails we get from the contact form, however, there is no database persistence, which is the proper solution. Further, mucking about in the code quickly and easily breaks Magento in unexpected and surprising ways, hence why my normal Magento reply on here is to strongly urge people to buy extensions. If you're asking the kind of questions like I would ask, you don't know enough to make a professional extension... buy a few proper extensions, analyze them, spend lots of time trying to figure it out.

Any more there are plenty of extensions competing to do the same tasks, so there should be something already working to do what you want.